# Error in running Clutter sample code in Mint

Tags: c, compiler-errors, gtk, gnome, clutter

I downloaded clutter from LFS (Ver 1.12.2) and tried running the example from Netbeans .
I have included libclutter in the project but i am getting following error :

**undefined symbol: clutter_actor_set_pivot_point**

Any suggestions or experience ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was something weird ... Finally found Might be useful for somebody later

Mint already had some files in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu for libclutter .. Netbeans was reading from there .. a quick readelf showed clutter_actor_set_pivot_point is not there ..

But after fresh installation of libclutter1.12.2 files went to /usr/local/lib/libclutter-1.0.so.0

Just remove the files in i386-linux-gnu folder and copy paste from usr>local>lib

Comment: Doing things like this is almost certain to break your system eventually. You either need to compile/install clutter in the same location as your distribution does (which also carries risks),or tell your system to look in the /usr/local/lib by adding it to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable